# How can I convert column to row data in PLSQL? I want to insert data in given format

Tags: plsql

I have data like shown below

| TDC_NO | C_MIN | C_MAX | MN_MIN | MN_MAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS24 | 0.06 | 0.12 | 0.45 | 0.65 |
| HX11 | 0.14 | 0.16 | 0.55 | 0.6 |

But I want in the format as shown below:

| tdc_no | element | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS24 | c | 0.06 | 0.12 |
| BS24 | MN | 0.45 | 0.65 |
| HX11 | C | 0.14 | 0.16 |
| HX11 | MN | 0.55 | 0.6 |

Answer (score 1):

Since I have no given query, I will have to go off an example here.

You can accomplish this in many ways, but for your given problem this could easily work. You could potentially solve in many other ways.

This is the easiest way probably:

```
SELECT r.tdc_no, r.element, r.min, r.max
FROM (
SELECT tdc_no, 'c' element, c_min min, c_max max
FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT tdc_no, 'MN' element, mn_min min, mn_max max
FROM table ) r
ORDER BY 1;
```